# UK fiance visa - PIP benefit amount and bank statements mix-up

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

i (the sponsor) just paid for the fiance visa application.

in the application, since i receive PIP benefit, it asked me how much of it was received in the past 12 months, so i counted through my online transactions and put the total.

afterwards i realised i was counting via my online bank transactions, that show my most recent transactions but not any of my actual details (name, account details etc).

i then found the proper monthly summary statements that show these, but they are missing most of last months transactions, as it only goes up to the 12th of each month, in this case 12th of june.

so this means now that my 12 months of financial proof don't match the number i wrote in the application of what i have received via PIP.

my next bank statement is only available on the 12th, which means it would now be after the application, which does not seem to be allowed and i'm guessing i can't wait anyway, because that would be too many days away from the statement date and would show transactions after the application date.

refund and reapply?

Comment: When did you start to receive PIP? Rates are fixed annually from April AFAIK (and UKVI will know this), so you could submit the decision letter for your claim and explain your calculation ‘error’ in a covering letter rather than cancelling the application and starting again.

Comment: This should be moved to Expats. But just to reassure you, no need to cancel just correct any errors in a cover letter.

Comment: @Traveller that was also a question i answered in the application that i was confused on. i stated the earliest available date via a letter i have which was around 2008. I just had an assessment decision letter back in may, stating my newest payment amounts i am to receive and also back pay i have received.

Comment: @Traveller I have a one page cover letter written to explain the relationship etc, so should i make a separate cover letter and place that with/before the pip letter?

Comment: @PeanutMooncake You might just be suffering from the typical ‘post-application anxiety’ but if you have real confusion over how you answered questions in the application, it might be best to cancel this one and resubmit once you’re confident you have understood the requirements. Personally I would only ever submit *one* covering letter and I would limit that to one page max - ECOs have to wade through a lot of supporting evidence, you need to make that task as easy as you can for them.

Comment: @Traveller Fully disagree, this is such a minor and clearly inadvertent discrepancy, and easy to correct in a cover letter. Applications don't get refused for minor errors like this but for fundamental issues. Cancelling and reapplying can lead to more issues such as the application not being properly withdrawn, and waiting for refunds.

Comment: @Traveller if i can rectify it via saying the bank statements i'm providing don't show all the amounts i originally added up and the pip decision letter states one of the amounts missing from the provided statements... then that would be great, just from what i've seen they can overlook things

Comment: @MJeffryes I’m **not** suggesting that the OP withdraws this application for a *minor error* that needs a *brief* explanation in *one* succinct cover letter. Personally I wouldn’t have pressed the submit button until I was 100% sure the application was as good as I could make it. If the OP has a lot of ‘post submission questions’ (which I accept may not be the case), that could be a refusal risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning comments into an answer: As @MJeffryes says, no need to cancel. This is such a minor and clearly inadvertent discrepancy, it is easy to correct in a cover letter. Applications don't get refused for minor errors like this but for fundamental issues. Cancelling and reapplying can lead to more issues, such as the application not being properly withdrawn, and waiting for refunds.

*However*, in a question [Help/Critique: - UK 2yr Visitor Visa (China - Super priority application)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/177916/help-critique-uk-2yr-visitor-visa-china-super-priority-application) from Dec 2022 you describe your relationship as being online only at that time, while in a very recent comment you say that you did not proceed down the visitor visa route. It therefore seems possible that your relationship with your fiancé remains online only.   Having met *in person* is a requirement of paragraph A290 (ii) of the [UK’s Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-8-family-members) pertaining to fiancés and proposed civil partners. Not having met in person prior to submitting your fiancé application would be a fundamental issue that cannot be corrected in a cover letter.